# Symfony 3 -The identifier id is missing for a query

Tags: symfony, request, http-delete

Some requests that I am making by Ajax to the server are giving an error that says "The identifier id is missing for a query", but if I am sending the parameter. The unusual thing is that this only happens from Cuba because if I enter the system through a VPN, this error does not appear and the parameter arrives well.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, passing the app from http to https solved the problem without changing a single line of code.

"no-referrer-when-downgrade (default)
This is the default behavior if no policy is specified, or if the provided value is invalid. The origin, path, and querystring of the URL are sent as a referrer when the protocol security level stays the same (HTTP → HTTP, HTTPS → HTTPS) or improves (HTTP → HTTPS), but isn't sent to less secure destinations ( HTTPS → HTTP)."
you can find more information here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy